# Elementry probability question - counter probability or addition.

Tags: probability

Say there are 5 red balls, 7 blue balls and 8 green balls, the probability of taking 2 balls (each time one ball) of different colour could be calculated

1. chance of taking red and blue  $ \Biggl(\frac{5}{5+7+8}*\frac{7}{5+7+8-1}\Biggr)*2$

chance of taking red and green $ \Biggl(\frac{5}{5+7+8}*\frac{8}{5+7+8-1}\Biggr)*2$

chance of taking blue and green $ \Biggl(\frac{7}{5+7+8}*\frac{8}{5+7+8-1}\Biggr)*2$

Adding these all up gives a probability of roughly 0.54

2. counter-probability (1-the probability of the second ball being the same as the first): $$ P= 1-\left(\frac{5}{5+7+8}\right)\left(\frac{4}{5+7+8-1}\right)-\left(\frac{7}{5+7+8}\right)\left(\frac{6}{5+7+8-1}\right)-\left(\frac{8}{5+7+8}\right)\left(\frac{7}{5+7+8-1}\right) = 0.69 $$

Now, I'm wondering how these two different methods yield different answers. They should be the same right?  Can someone explain why this happens?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your first calculation looks wrong.  You should get $\frac{70+80+112}{380} \approx 0.69$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods should indeed give the same result.  You must have an arithmetic error.

"*Adding these all up gives a probability of roughly $0.54$*"

[No they don't](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%2F20*7%2F19+*+2+%2B+5%2F20*8%2F19+*+2+%2B+7%2F20*8%2F19*2).  Perhaps you forgot to multiply the last term by two?

Comment: +1 for spotting the actual error

Comment: yeah thats right ,,, thanks, i calculated everything on paper.... sry